# What's the general principle behind choosing saving vs. paying off debt?

Tags: canada, retirement, savings, debt

In "general" is it better to pay off one's debt (line of credit, etc.) or is it better to invest (retirement account / RRSP or the like)? I understand that the answer will depend on terms of debt and amount of debt, inter alia, and perhaps saving and paying off debt. But I am seeking to understand the the principle that determines the answer, not the particularities that might govern one's decision.

So, at what point does the emphasis shift from one to the other?

What variables are at play here?

With thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It has to do with return. I don't know if Canada has a matching feature on retirement accounts, but in the US many companies will match the first X% you put in. So for me, my first $5000 or so is matched 100%. I'll take that match over paying down any debt. Beyond that, of course it's a simple matter of rate of return. Why save in the bank at 2% when you owe at 10-18%? 
One can make this as simple or convoluted as they like. My mortgage is a tax deduction so my 5% mortgage costs me 3.6%. I've continued to invest rather than pay the mortgage too early, as my retirement account is with pre-tax dollars. So $72 will put $100 in that account. Even in this last decade, bad as it was, I got more than 3.6% return.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Paying down debt is a good idea, but not if the money is more useful elsewhere (e.g. an employer-matched retirement contribution).

Answer (score 8):

Debt creates risk.  Plain and simple.  Comparing interest rates of debt vs. possible investing.  To me, it is all meaningless.  When you are in debt, you options are limited.  If you are not in debt, you have more freedom.

To me, it is a no brainer.  Become debt free ASAP.

Comment: In general, this is the approach I favor.  There are nuances, but by and large getting debt free is a priority.

Comment: Plus, what will help you sleep better at night?  Being debt free, or being in debt?  I know this is tagged as a Canada question, but look what got the US into a lot of the mess we are in now; leverage.  Which is just a fancy way of saying debt.

Comment: Also, would you go into debt to invest money?  If the answer is no, then why stay in debt to invest?

Comment: I think your answer is an oversimplification.  Why should I pay off my car loan with a 1.9% interest rate when I can keep that money in an investment with a 4-5% yield?  Just so I can claim to be "debt free"?  Debt is a TOOL.  You just have to use it properly and not hurt yourself.

Comment: I'd add that not all debt is unhealthy. For example, I wouldn't suggest forgoing putting money in savings to pay off a house or car loan early unless you got into loans that are really more than you can comfortably handle. However, paying off credit cards before saving is probably smart.

Comment: For a house, yes I would invest money for my retirement before paying down the mortgage.  For a car, I would still pay it off quickly.  It is a depreciating asset.  All of that interest you are paying, even at 1.9%, is on something which will be worth next to nothing at the end of its life.  So I'd rather pay it all off, and then invest.

Comment: I'm not sure what the car's depreciation has to do with anything (unless maybe I was trying to sell it immediately).  Say I fell into $5000.  I could immediately pay off the balance of my 1.9% car loan, or I could invest that money into something with a >2.0% yield (stock fund, CD, whatever).  Investing the money and letting the loan continue makes more sense.  The profit from the investment exceeds what I would be paying in interest.  (NOTE: You make sure you take the taxes on the investment into account.)

Comment: Way too simplified. You can't answer this question without talking about the interest rate on your debt, and your expected returns on your investments, and the tax issues associated with each.

Comment: Mike, money not put into a matched 401(k) is lost forever. The $3000 you'd use to pay off some low interest debt can be $4000 pretax deposited to the 401(k) account, and matched to become $8000. The obsession to be 100% debt free comes at its own price.

Comment: "Debt creates risk" - an interesting statement. I've been pondering it for the past 3 years. A bank lends me money and charges me interest based on the risk that I wont pay it back. When I borrow to buy a house instead of depleting my savings, my liquidity hasn't gone down, but up. The bank has increased its risk, not me. Buying all cash, or paying off my mortgage to where I have no money left? That's risky.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer _The bank has increased its risk, not me._  Your risk of bankruptcy has **possibly** increased (depending on your net worth).

Comment: @user209436 - the $200k I deposited to my 401(k) went in pretax, or $266k, which was matched to $532k. I'd say my own situation is far better than to have thrown the money to the mortgage and have deposited 500k less to my retirement. The matched 401(k) should take priority over nearly any other choice. Including credit card debt.

Answer (score 4):

Think of yourself as a business with two accounts, "cash" and "net worth". Your goal is to make money.

"Cash" is what you need to meet your obligations. You need to pay your rent/mortgage, utilities, buy food, pay for transportation, service debt, etc. If you make $100 a month, and your obligations are $90, you're clearing $10.

"Net worth" are assets that you own, including cash, retirement savings, investments, or even tangible goods like real property or items you collect with value.

The "pay off debt" versus "save money" debate, in my opinion, is driven by two things, in this order:

- Affect on your cash flow. (Think liquid cash)
- Absolute return. (Think investments that are less liquid, like a CD, or mutual fund with capital gains)

If you start saving too soon, you'll have a hard time getting by when your car suddenly needs a $500 repair or you need a new furnace. You need to improve your cash flow so that you actually have discretionary income. Pay off those credit cards, then start directing those old payments into savings and investments.

Answer (score 3):

Depends upon the debt cost. Assuming it is consumer debt or credit card debt, it is better to pay that off first, it is the best investment you can make.

Let's say it is credit card debt. If you pay 18% interst and have for example a $1,000 amount. If you pay it off you save $180 in interest ($1,000 times 18%). You would have to earn 18% on 1,000 to generate $180  if it was in aninvestment.

Here is a link discussing ways of [reducing debt](http://www.gorrfinancial.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56)

Once you have debt paid off you have the cashflow to begin building wealth. The key is in the cashflow.